# Installing Chrome extensions when --user-agent flag is overridden

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

At work I'm behind a proxy that kills traffic from Google Chrome, by detecting the `User-Agent`. I can get around this by overriding the `--user-agent` option and setting it to Safari. The problem is that I now cannot install any Chrome extensions because Google's website specifically looks for "Chrome" in the `User-Agent` variable. Does anyone know of a way to get around this, and trick google into installing a Chrome extension?

**EDIT** : I tried setting `U-A` to "Chromium" already and that is also blocked.

Comment: Man what kind of workplace is it...

Comment: I work in a highly regulated industry. At least they don't force us to use IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is figure out URL to an extension, then you can just download it in any browser and drag the file over Chrome window to install it. Extension URL has the following format:

```
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D<EXTENSION_ID>%26uc%26lang%3Den-US&prod=chrome&prodversion=11.0.696.16
```

If you go to extension gallery in any browser you can get extension id from the url:

```
/detail/<EXTENSION_ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your user-agent to "Chromium"?

Comment: Does chrome refer to a different DLL for user-agent when using incognito mode?

Comment: I'm not doing the DLL override, although I did try that and it was still blocked. How does incognito affect `U-A`?